# Position:absolute is not to the nearest positioned ancestor

Tags: html, css

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<div class="header-content mx-auto" style='margin-top:-250px;'>
    <div class='circle' id='yellow' style='background-color:#FFBE00'></div>
    <div class='circle' id='grey' style='background-color:#9A8966'></div>
    <div class='circle' id='pink' style='background-color:blue'></div>
    <div class='circle' id='darkred' style='background-color:#B90808'></div>
    <div class='circle' id='red' style='background-color:#F91000'></div>
    <h1 class="mb-5" style='width:1000px;'>
        <span id='I'>I</span>
        <span id='Am'>Am</span>
        <span id='your'>Y</span>
        <span id='cognitive'>c</span>
        <span id='assistant'>A</span>
    </h1>
    <div style='width:500px;height:200px;margin-top:100px;background-color:red' id='container'>
        <div style='position:absolute;left:70px;height:30px;width:100px;background-color:green;'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The latest div element is positioned absolute but it is not relative the nearest ancestor which would be #container. Why is that? It is positioned relative to #header-content.

Answer (score 1):

> An element is positioned with respect to a relative positioned
>   parent. You have to specify the position relative on the parent with
>   which you want to position the child element. If there is no
>   positioned parent, then by default all absolute positioned elements
>   use body to position themself.

So, in your case the last div is not positioned with respect to `#container` because it's not given `position:relative` and also it's not positioned relative to the `header-content` but it is positioned relative to the `body`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your content is wrapped in the #container div. It won't be relative to this div because it has not a relative property. Add position: relative; to this and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `#container` to `position: relative`

All `absolute` positioned elements are rendered relative to the next `relative` parent. Yet the initial value for `position` is `static` which gets ignored by absolute elements.